# Is there a way to use sscanf with stdin?

Tags: c, stdin, scanf

I have a program that either takes data from a file or from the standard input. 
I wrote code for scanning the file using sscanf.
I was wondering if I could reuse that code but with stdin instead of using scanf?

Ex:

How could I modify this so that it works with standard input?

```
while(fgets(buffer, MAX_LEN, input) != NULL) { 
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%s %s %s", one, two, three) == 3) { } 
}
```

Comment: sscanf parses data from a char*. so there is no file at all. You probably want to read from stdin into buffer, instead of reading into buffer from some file.

Comment: Have a look at fscanf which can read from stdin

Comment: Maybe what you need is `fscanf`, the first parameter will specify the data source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change the `sscanf()` call - it's the `fgets()` call that is reading from the input file.

You can change your code snippet to work with `stdin` by literally replacing `input` with `stdin` in the `fgets()` call (`stdin` is a global `FILE *` declared in `stdio.h` that refers to standard input).

Comment: Of course, you can also assign `input = stdin;`, since it's just a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The third argument in `fgets(buffer,MAX_LEN,input)` i.e. `input` is the source from where the input is to be taken.In your case it should be replaced with `stdin` so that it takes input from standard console instead of file.

Answer (score -1):

fscanf: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/

Comment: Kidding right? If the person asking the question knows how to use both fgets and scanf, they most certainly know how to use fscanf. They clearly just didn't know of it's existence.

Comment: Bizarre how you you post this criticism and yet someone else also recommended scanf in a comment and gets 5 upvotes. No consistency on this website.